# Не работает унарный минус на INT_MIN

Tags: c, операторы

Если попытаться применить операцию унарного минуса к числу типа `int`, содержащее `INT_MIN`, то ничего не изменяется.

Собственно сабж:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a = INT_MIN;

    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    a = -a;
    printf("a = %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Результат работы (компилятор - Clang):

```
a = -2147483648
a = -2147483648
```

В чем проблема?

P.S. стандарт c99 никакие ограничения (вроде) не накладывает:

> 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators
>   ...
>   The result of the unary - operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer
>   promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the
>   promoted type.

Comment: А что вы хотели получить? Если положительное число в тип данных не влазит.

Comment: @pavel, почему не влазит? Должно ведь получиться INT_MAX?

Comment: Нет, не должно, как минимум потому что `INT_MIN = -2147483648`, в то время как `INT_MAX = 2147483647`.

Comment: @iksuy,  да, точно.

Comment: Но вообще я что-то сам не очень понял почему так происходит. Если унарный минус просто меняет знак, то должен получится 0, если же делается еще инверсия битов, до должно быть `INT_MAX`. Хорошо бы кто дал полный ответ с описанием как это происходит в битовом представлении.

Comment: @iksuy, арифметическое отрицание — это инверсия с последующим прибавлением единицы (пр: `-0 = ~0 + 1 = 0b11...11 + 1 = (переполнение) = 0 `). Вот и всё, даже на полноценный ответ не набирается

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Why does -INT_MIN = INT_MIN in a signed, two's complement representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8917233/4279)

Comment: @iksuy возможно, на примере трёх бит станет понятнее: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31378616/2076787

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-INT_MIN` значение ведёт к неопределённому поведению (undefined behavior) в Си из-за переполнения (integer overflow). Это не только теоретическая проблема, [к примеру](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8917528/4279):

```
#define abs(x) ((x) > 0 ? (x) : -(x)) 

int foo(int x){  
    return abs(x) >= 0;
}
```

может быть [скомпилировано в](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23define+abs(x)+((x)+%3E+0+%3F+(x)+:+-(x))+%0A%0Aint+foo(int+x)%7B++%0A++++return+abs(x)+%3E%3D+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.71193866374589,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'1',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),fontScale:0.8957951999999999,libs:!(),options:'-Os',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:49.28806133625411,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
mov     eax, 1
ret
```

то есть даже для `INT_MIN` возвращается `1` вне зависимости от того как int представлен, то есть даже на реализациях где [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5) используется, где `-n` может вернуть `INT_MIN`.

Переполнение возникает так как `INT_MIN` по модулю математически может быть больше `INT_MAX`.

`n == -n` получается в дополнительном коде, так как унарный минус можно реализовать как: обратить биты, прибавить один: [`-n == ~n+1`](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html#whyworks). К примеру, [для 8-битного числа](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Most_negative_number):

```
n=-128 1000 0000  
~n     0111 1111
~n+1   1000 0000
```

Comment: Это вы очень хороший пример с упрощением функции `foo` привели. Способы интерпретации UB-выражений современными компиляторами не перестают меня удивлять.